# When to choose socket programming over WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, network-programming

What are some actual, realistic situations that one would need to use raw socket programming over WCF? I know performance is one, but are there any others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be situations where you are talking to a third party system that requires communication via sockets (we have to with one).

Answer (score 0):

When the software at the other end of the connection knows nothing about .NET or WCF - the WCF netTcpBinding assumes both ends are implemented using WCF.

Answer (score 0):

say you need to send receive commands from a external device which does not support WCF communication. 
Say you would want to pass some commands to a device connected to your serial port.